# JQWidgets jqxGrid: how to get a dropdown from rowcell

Tags: jqxgrid, jqwidget

i have a jqxgrid with a dropdown column. Now, if in a row a dropdown item is selected, this dropdown item should be deactivated in all following rows.

So, first i have to get all rows:

```
var rows = $('#jqxgridpop').jqxGrid('getboundrows');
```

then get all cells containing the dropdown

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   var cell = $('#jqxgridpop').jqxGrid('getcell', i, 'languageddl');
```

and then, whit some magic, get the dropdowncontrol from the cell to disable the item. This is where i’m stuck..

Any hints or is this not possible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I became an answer on the jqwidget forums, here the solution:

```
editor.bind('open', function (event) {
var rows = $('#jqxgridpop').jqxGrid('getboundrows');
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var value = $('#jqxgridpop').jqxGrid('getcellvalue', i, "languageCode");
    var item = editor.jqxDropDownList('getItemByValue', value);
    editor.jqxDropDownList('disableItem', item);
};
});
```